# MediaWiki 1.35 parsoid timeout trying use VisualEditor

Tags: mediawiki

I've installed mediawiki on an Amazon ec2 server.
The server has only apache, php, mariadb and mediawiki

I'm using mediawiki 1.35, with the bundled VisualEditor and ParsoidPHP
I can use VisualEditor to edit a new page, but it will not save, and when I edit an existing page, I get the blue progress bar followed by the error:
**Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: (curl error: 28) Timeout was reached**
I've tried configuring parsoid using instruction I've found on the web :

```
$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid'] = [
        // URL to the Parsoid instance - use port 8142 if you use the Debian package - the parameter 'URL' was first used but is now deprecated (string)
        'url' => 'http://myIpAddress:8000',
        // Parsoid "domain" (string, optional) - MediaWiki >= 1.26
        'domain' => 'myIpAddress',
        // Parsoid "prefix" (string, optional) - deprecated since MediaWiki 1.26, use 'domain'
        'prefix' => 'myIpAddress',
        // Forward cookies in the case of private wikis (string or false, optional)
        'forwardCookies' => true,
        // request timeout in seconds (integer or null, optional)
        'timeout' => null,
        // Parsoid HTTP proxy (string or null, optional)
        'HTTPProxy' => null,
        // whether to parse URL as if they were meant for RESTBase (boolean or null, optional)
        'restbaseCompat' => null,
];
```

The best effect I get is a 404, or a 400. This configuration is not working.
I haven't made any other changes to the settings.

if I call parsoid directly:
http://MyIpAddress/api.php?action=visualeditor&paction=parse&page=Main_Page

I see the timeout thusly:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "apierror-visualeditor-docserver-http-error",
        "info": "Error contacting the Parsoid/RESTBase server: (curl error: 28) Timeout was reached",
        "*": "See http://MyIpAddress/api.php for API usage. Subscribe to the mediawiki-api-announce mailing list at &lt;https://lists.wikimedia.org/mailman/listinfo/mediawiki-api-announce&gt; for notice of API deprecations and breaking changes."
    }
}
```

Comment: It should work out of the box if you don't touch `$wgVirtualRestConfig` at all.

Comment: I only added the config after spending a lot of time with the error. I get the error whether it's there or not.

Comment: Having non-empty configuration for the Parsoid module *will* result in error (although normally I'd expect a different one) - see [this check](https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-VisualEditor/blob/REL1_35/includes/VisualEditorHooks.php#L64).

Answer (score 1):

Based on my testing, it appears that parsoid is using the $wgServer variable to make a local connection to rest.php
Using curl, I'm able to connect to http://**localhost**/rest.php/v1/page/Main_Page
But, not to http://**myipaddress**/rest.php/v1/page/Main_Page or http://**mydomainname**/rest.php/v1/page/Main_Page both of these timeout. The apache server can't connect to itself
So, theoretically, I should be able to set

```
$wgVirtualRestConfig['modules']['parsoid']['domain']='localhost';
```

But that results in a 404, instead of a timeout.

In the end, I added my domain name to /etc/hosts and pointed it to 127.0.0.1 and that works fine. It feels like a hack, and I must use a domain name, not just an iP.

Answer (score 1):

We've run into this problem several times.

In one case, it was a matter of access control.

Parsoid makes HTTP requests to the MediaWiki site. We're restricting access to certain actions using [the Lockdown extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Lockdown),
and we had to exempt Parsoid, which can be done in several ways, e.g.:

```
if (($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== '127.0.0.1') && ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] !== $_
SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'])) {
# don't lock down any pages for Parsoid, or the VisualEditor will break on them
    wfLoadExtension('Lockdown');
}
```